# Django: Get dropdown value and select dynamic form fields for Class Based views

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my current code (see below) I retrieve the selected value from a dropdown choicefield, e.g. the value '1'.

```
recipe_choice = request.GET.get('recipe_select', False)
```

I use this value in an IF logic to choose among different forms, such as

```
if recipe_choice == '1':
        ingredients_form = HamburgerForm(request.POST)
```

Then I return a Context that consist of my dropdown choicefield and selected form.

It all works fine when I call it as a function and can use "Request" to extract my drop-down choice as a GET.

E.g. as a function:

```
path('cooking/', cooking, name="cooking")
```

However, I would like to ask how I can get the same result when using Class Based FormView instead, Such as:

```
path('cooking/', CookingView.as_view(), name="cooking")
```

The problem I experience is that I cannot retrieve the selected value from a dropdown and cannot find it within the get_context_data to use it within an IF statement, thus cannot translate my old function into a new CookingView(FormView):

```
class CookingView(FormView):
    form_class = CookingForm
    template_name = 'form/cooking.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        """
       # some logic to get a desired form, such as

        ingredients_form = []
        if recipe_choice == '1':
            ingredients_form = HamburgerForm(request.POST)
        elif recipe_choice == '2':
            ingredients_form = PancakeForm(request.POST)

        """

        context = super(CookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ingridients_form'] = ingredients_form
        return context
```

Q: How do I get this logic into a Class Based FormView?

***Below I provide my current code that works (as a function).***

***views.py***

```
def cooking(request):
    context = {}
    recipe_choice = request.GET.get('recipe_select', False)

    ingredients_form = []
    if recipe_choice == '1':
        ingredients_form = HamburgerForm(request.POST)
    elif recipe_choice == '2':
        ingredients_form = PancakeForm(request.POST)

    context['cookbook_form'] = CookingForm(request.GET or None)
    context['ingridients_form'] = ingredients_form

    return render(request, 'form/cooking.html', context)
```

***models.py***

```
class Ingridients(models.Model):
    # for hamburgers
    cheese  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ham     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    onion   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bread   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ketchup = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # for pancakes
    milk    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    butter  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    honey   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    eggs    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

***forms.py***

```
class CookingForm(Form):
    RECIPES = (
        (1, 'Hamburger'),
        (2, 'Pancakes')
    )
    recipe_select = ChoiceField(choices=RECIPES)


class HamburgerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingridients
        fields = ['cheese', 'ham', 'onion', 'bread', 'ketchup']

class PancakeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingridients
        fields = ['milk', 'butter', 'honey', 'eggs']
```

***cooking.html***

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form id="cookselect_form" method="GET">
    {{ cookbook_form|crispy }}
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Choose Recipe</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form id="ingridientslist_form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy ingridients_form %}
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can approach like this:

I am overriding the `get_form_class` method, to decide which form to render between HamburgerForm and PancakeForm. Then I am passing `CookingForm` as context in `get_context_data` method.

```
class CookingView(FormView):
    template_name = 'form/cooking.html'
     success_url = '/some_url/'

    def get_form_class(self):
       recipe_choice = self.request.GET.get('recipe_select', '1')
       if recipe_choice == '1':
        return HamburgerForm
       elif recipe_choice == '2':
        return PancakeForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cookbook_form'] = CookingForm()
        return context
```

And I am updating the template as well(using `form` instead of `ingridients_form`).

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form id="cookselect_form" method="GET">
    {{ cookbook_form|crispy }}
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Choose Recipe</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form id="ingridientslist_form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer! 

I made a small amendment to achieve:
A. Displaying an initial empty form with drop down value Choose Dish
B, That value chosen in drop down stays selected and correspond to displayed recipe form.

I did this by:
1. Created an extra form 0, an empty form, with choice field (0, 'Choose Dish')
2. Made it as default, recipe_choice = self.request.GET.get('recipe_select', default='0')
3. When calling Cookbook_form, using the value in the drop down and display choice with its recipe_choice.
context['cookbook_form'] = CookingForm(self.request.GET or None)